# kohana sends newline before template content

Tags: kohana, newline

This is a Kohana framework site I am working with.

I have a website and have several controllers that work fine. One of the controllers has begun to send a newline character before the template output and that breaks the page layout.

Instead of sending <!DOCTYPE as the first part of the template output it sends hex "0A" newline before the <!DOCTYPE string.  I tried to remove the first character of the template output but all that did was change <!DOCTYPE to !DOCTYPE. So I am assuming that the template output is complete and correct without the newline. But somewhere that newline is being added and then the template is displayed.

Here is the line to display the content which all checks out
$this->template->content = $content;

What is displayed is (in hex) "0A -- 3C 21 44 4F 43 54  59 50 45".

Can anyone help???

UPDATE: for anyone who has a similar problem.

The problem was caused by some bad code in the model which was generating a newline output.
The template was being rendered but only after the model had previously output that newline. Causing the page to "break".

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the newline is not in a the template file? You say `one of my controllers`, does it only happen on particular pages?

Comment: Newline not in template file.

Comment: It only happens in one controller. The others work fine. Some of the other controllers use the same template file and don't send out newlines. So I am pretty sure its a problem with this one controller.

Comment: Could you post the code of that controller?

Comment: AmazingDreams - sorry I cannot post it as I do not own the code  its owned by my client. It's about 5000 lines of code which is a bit bulky :-)

Comment: If that is the case. We cannot do anything but guess. Look for lost `echo`s, `print`s, `Debug::vars`s. Perhaps there is a newline at the top of the controller? At the bottom? Does it happen on all actions?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your controller and view using UTF-8 **without BOM**. You can do that with Notepad++, open file and from *Encoding* menu select: *Encode in UTF-8  without BOM*.

Comment: Tried opening file and encoding as advised then saved the controller. Loaded it to the server and it still sends out a newline first.

Comment: This hex character can be caused by some whitespace in the view, if you cannot post your controller code, could you post your view?

Comment: VisualFanatic - I cannot post the view either as I don't own the code. However, I would be interested in knowing if the view (which is loaded into the center of the template) could actually cause a newline to be added before the template itself.